# Is 'compromisation' actually used, or is there a better word?

Tags: word-usage, nouns

I'm writing an IT security related text and instinctively wrote the word "compromisation".

When I thought about it, I wasn't too sure anymore, so I check and the only actual reference to the word I found was on [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compromisation).

Spell checks in my browser or MS Word don't know it either.

How I wanted to use it:

Attacker X used method Y to *compromise* system Z. (this seems fine to me)

Method Y lead to a **compromisation** of system Z. (this is what I attempted to use, but doesn't seem to be right)

**Q:** Is compromisation actually used in the English language or is there a better word for this?

*edit:* I've also come across [this post in a forum](https://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=1477473), where the same question was asked, without conclusion.

Comment: Keep in mind that Wiktionary is not created by lexicographers, so when you come across a word there that you can't find in other dictionaries, you should look at the "Citations" page and the "History" page to get a better understanding of how the word got into Wiktionary. When I look over the edit history for the entry, it doesn't seem like compromisation is a good word to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although a search on the Internet shows some dictionaries defining *compromisation* as "the act of compromising", it is not commonly used, and might even be grammatically incorrect (I too can't find an authoritative conclusion on this).

However, it is better replaced by an appropriate use of the word **compromise**.

> *QUESTIONABLE*: Method Y lead to a **compromisation** of system Z.
>
> *PREFERABLE*: Method Y led to a **compromise** of system Z.
>
> *PREFERABLE*: Method Y led to system Z **being compromised**.

In this context, *compromise* is used to mean breaching a system.

There is another use of *compromise* which means to arrive at a mutually agreeable settlement.

> *QUESTIONABLE*: The two parties in the accident did a **compromisation**.
>
> *PREFERABLE*: The two parties in the accident arrived at a **compromise**.
>
> *PREFERABLE*: The two parties in the accident **compromised** by agreeing to pay for their own repairs.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just realised that "breach" would also be a good alternative.

Comment: @SaAtomic - good one, _breach_ is also a commonly accepted word in IT security to describe this.